# Failed to connect: 111 Connection refused

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

Is there any way to send the iOS push notifications if I am using the shared hosting, because the port 2195 is closed on Godaddy shared hosting(as you must be aware of that).
So the notifications can't work here?

EDIT:

```
<?php 
$deviceToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX888';
    // Put your private key's passphrase here:
    $passphrase = '';

    // Put your alert message here:
    $message = 'Hello';

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//echo dirname(__FILE__);die;
    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', dirname(__FILE__).'/ck.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
echo "No";
    // Open a connection to the APNS server
    $fp = stream_socket_client(
        'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
        $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

    echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

    // Create the payload body
    $body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => $message,
        'sound' => 'default'
        );

    // Encode the payload as JSON
    $payload = json_encode($body);

    // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    if (!$result)
    {   
        echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    else
    {   
        echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

    }

    // Close the connection to the server
    fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: Dude, get a VPS for $5 or $10 and forget shared hosting. DigitalOcean and Linode are both excellent.

Comment: show your code how you sending notification

Comment: @AmitGaud: code posted, well this is not the first time I am doing this push notifications task, the question is can it work on other ports other than 2195?

Comment: any solution you found @VishalParkash